# Source of aggressively toned texts for machine learning

Tags: sentiment-analysis

As suggested in [comment on data science SA](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/source-of-aggressively-toned-texts-for-machine-learning?noredirect=1#comment7040_6621) I reposted the question to this site, which seems a better fit for this type of question.

I was looking for a source where there would be an extended amount of texts with aggressive tone. It can be intertwined with non-aggressive texts, but it would be good if the ratio of aggressive texts to non-aggressive texts be no less then 1:5.

I was thinking about discussion forums which would be discussing the immigrants issue with contributors of lesser mind who would be very hateful and xenofobic. Or supporters of extreme political parties.

The content being spoken about is not really important, the more diverse it would be the better.

In the past I was looking for a less specific sentiment like "like/dislike" something for which reviews of movies on IMDB were an ideal source and I had some good results.

However it is very difficult to find a base of data with aggressive sentiment or at least some good internet sources from which the data could be gathered.

Do you have any ideas on how I could gather up such data?

Comment: [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com).

Comment: A did look into it, but it was hard to get to a consitent plain aggressive content. If you have some subreddits or good tags/keywords, which result in consistent stream of aggressive text/data, a good query, I will be happy to try.

Comment: I was not entirely serious and I don't have a complete answer to your question.  Consistently aggressive may be hard.  Maybe you can find transcripts of some right-wing U.S. talk radio?